# Android XML parsing using SAX

Tags: android, xml, parsing, sax

I'm trying to parse this xml:

```
<exchangerate>
<exchangerate ccy="AMD" ccy_name_ru="Армянский драм " ccy_name_ua="Вiрменський драм " ccy_name_en="Armenian Dram " base_ccy="RU" buy="805393" unit="1000.00000" date="2014.01.09"/>
<exchangerate ccy="AUD" ccy_name_ru="Австралийский доллар " ccy_name_ua="Австралiйський долар " ccy_name_en="Australian Dollar " base_ccy="RU" buy="291544" unit="1.00000" date="2014.01.09"/>
</exchangerate>
```

But cannt understand how can i get ccy, ccy_name_ru... and other attr.

Early i'm parsing this xml:

```
<rss xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" version="2.0">
<channel>
<atom:link href="http://dengi-banki-kredit.webnode.ru/rss/novosti.xml" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml"/>
<title>
<![CDATA[ Новости - dengi-banki-kredit.webnode.ru ]]>
</title>
<link>http://dengi-banki-kredit.webnode.ru</link>
<language>ru</language>
<pubDate>Fri, 11 Jan 2013 07:25:00 +0100</pubDate>
<lastBuildDate>Fri, 11 Jan 2013 07:25:00 +0100</lastBuildDate>
<category>
<![CDATA[ Новости ]]>
</category>
<docs>http://blogs.law.harvard.edu/tech/rss</docs>
<generator>Webnode</generator>
<item>
<title>
<![CDATA[
Росбанк провел новогоднюю благотворительную акцию в поддержку детей
]]>
</title>
<link>
http://dengi-banki-kredit.webnode.ru/news/rosbank-provjel-novogodnjuju-blagotvoritjelnuju-aktsiju-v-poddjerzhku-djetjej/
</link>
<description>
<![CDATA[
Сотрудники Росбанка в рамках базара могли приобрести оригинальные новогодние сувениры, сделанные детьми-сиротами и молодыми людьми с ограниченными возможностями, говорится в сообщении кредитной организации. &nbsp; В базаре приняли участие общественная организация «Художественный центр «Дети Марии», благотворительный проект «Социальные метры», межрегиональная общественная организация помощи детям с особенностями развития и их семьям «Дорога в мир», Центр равных возможностей «Вверх» и свои...
]]>
</description>
<pubDate>Fri, 11 Jan 2013 07:25:00 +0100</pubDate>
<guid isPermaLink="true">
http://dengi-banki-kredit.webnode.ru/news/rosbank-provjel-novogodnjuju-blagotvoritjelnuju-aktsiju-v-poddjerzhku-djetjej/
</guid>
<category>Новости</category>
</item>
```

I do it with this code:

```
public class Parser {

    public static String url = null;

    class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<PostItem>> {

        @Override
        protected List<PostItem> doInBackground(String... params) {
            URL feedUrl;
            InputStream is = null;

            try {
                feedUrl = new URL(url);
                is = feedUrl.openConnection().getInputStream();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            final PostItem currentPost = new PostItem();
            final List<PostItem> messages = new ArrayList<PostItem>();
            RootElement root = new RootElement("rss");
            Element channel = root.getChild("channel");
            Element item = channel.getChild("item");
            item.setEndElementListener(new EndElementListener() {
                public void end() {
                    messages.add(currentPost.copy());
                }
            });
            item.getChild("title").setEndTextElementListener(
                    new EndTextElementListener() {
                        public void end(String body) {
                            currentPost.setTitle(body);
                        }
                    });
            item.getChild("link").setEndTextElementListener(
                    new EndTextElementListener() {
                        public void end(String body) {
                            currentPost.setLink(body);
                        }
                    });
            item.getChild("description").setEndTextElementListener(
                    new EndTextElementListener() {
                        public void end(String body) {
                            currentPost.setDescription(body);
                        }
                    });
            item.getChild("pubDate").setEndTextElementListener(
                    new EndTextElementListener() {
                        public void end(String body) {
                            currentPost.setDate(body);
                        }
                    });
            try {
                Xml.parse(is, Xml.Encoding.UTF_8, root.getContentHandler());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("MyTag", e.toString());
            }
            return messages;
        }
    }

    public List<PostItem> parse() {
        List<PostItem> result = null;
        MyTask mt = new MyTask();
        try {
            result = mt.execute("").get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

But i dont know how to do it with my new xml but in such way ?
Anybody can explain me this thing ?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all you have same tags inside each other. That is a mistake, you have to change the outer tag name like `<exchangerates>`. you can read attributes of a tag like this:

```
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    if (qName.equals("exchangerate")) {
                 map.put("ccy", attributes.getValue(0)); 
                 map.put("ccy_name_ru", attributes.getValue(1)); 
                 map.put("ccy_name_ua", attributes.getValue(2)); 
                 map.put("ccy_name_en", attributes.getValue(3)); 
                 map.put("base_ccy", attributes.getValue(4)); 
                 map.put("buy", attributes.getValue(5)); 
                 map.put("unit", attributes.getValue(6)); 
                 map.put("date", attributes.getValue(7)); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing ccy, ccy_name is called attributes.

Now in SAX parser you have below method

```
//opening element tag
public void startElement (String uri, String name, String qName, Attributes atts)
{
    //handle the start of an element
}
```

In that you are receiving all the attributes in `Attributes atts` parameters.

And you can write below code to get ccv
String strccv = atts.getValue("ccv");

Ideally your response should be like

```
<exchangerates>
<exchangerate ccy="AMD" ccy_name_ru="Армянский драм " ccy_name_ua="Вiрменський драм " ccy_name_en="Armenian Dram " base_ccy="RU" buy="805393" unit="1000.00000" date="2014.01.09"/>
<exchangerate ccy="AUD" ccy_name_ru="Австралийский доллар " ccy_name_ua="Австралiйський долар " ccy_name_en="Australian Dollar " base_ccy="RU" buy="291544" unit="1.00000" date="2014.01.09"/>
</exchangerates>
```

There we are differenciating parent tag with exchangerates and child tags with exchangerate

Comment: here is a link to xml file
https://privat24.privatbank.ua/p24/accountorder?oper=prp&PUREXML&apicour&country=&full

Comment: You want a parser code from my side ? O giving me the link for that similar tag thing ?